# How to make 1 call on backend endpoint instead of 2 on Header and Footer. Angular 10

Tags: angular, typescript, api, rest, observable

I have contact-info.service which get information about contacts for header and footer components. Everything is working, but BE received 2 calls instead of 1 for this 1 json. How I can refactor this code for making just 1 call on backend.

So, **contact-info.service.ts :**

```
export class ContactInfoService {
  private apiUrl: string;
  private endpoint = 'common/main-contact';

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {
    this.apiUrl = environment.backendUrl;
  }

  getContactInformation(): Observable<ContactInfo> {
    return this.http.get<ContactInfo>(`${this.apiUrl}/${this.endpoint}`)
    .pipe(shareReplay(1));
  }
}
```

**header.component.ts :**

```
export class HeaderComponent implements OnInit {
  contactInfo$: Observable<ContactInfo>;

  constructor(private contactInfoService: ContactInfoService) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.contactInfo$ = this.contactInfoService.getContactInformation().pipe(shareReplay(1));
  }

}
```

**footer.component.ts:**

```
export class FooterComponent implements OnInit {
  currentDate = new Date();

  contactInfo$: Observable<ContactInfo>;

  constructor(private contactInfoService: ContactInfoService) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.contactInfo$ = this.contactInfoService.getContactInformation().pipe(shareReplay(1));
  }
}
```

Comment: what do you mean by BE ?

Comment: @FaizalHussain I'm assuming 'backend', or rather the api

Comment: Yes, it's mean backend

Comment: Actually you're calling the api from header and footer. The best way is to call the API from the header and pass it to the footer using behavior subject

Comment: @OlehZ This might help: [sharing data between angular components](https://fireship.io/lessons/sharing-data-between-angular-components-four-methods/#unrelated-components-sharing-data-with-a-service)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your service should look like below -

```
 export class ContactInfoService implements OnInit {
      private apiUrl: string;
      private endpoint = 'common/main-contact';
      private dataObs;
      constructor(private http: HttpClient) {
        this.apiUrl = environment.backendUrl;
        this.callContactInfo();
      }
     callContactInfo(){
       this.dataObs =  this.http.get<ContactInfo>(`${this.apiUrl}/${this.endpoint}`)
        .pipe(shareReplay(1));
    }
    
      getContactInformation(): Observable<ContactInfo> {
        return this.dataObs;
      }
    }
```

You can directly use `getContactInformation()` in your template without using `pipe(shareReplay(1))` in header and footer or better approach is to store the observable returned from `getContactInformation()` in your components variable and use it in your template with async pipe.

Comment: I tried with this code, but in this case I can't see request in networks any more. Maybe I should'nt use async pipe in template?

Comment: @OlehZ I've updated my answer. You don't need to `pipe(shareReplay(1))` again in your header or footer. Either subscribe it directly or use it in your template using async pipe.

Comment: When console.log(this.contactInfo$) in component ngOnInit it takes me undefined in this case :(

Comment: Which You mean?

Comment: Your `console.log(this.contactInfo$)`

Comment: export class FooterComponent implements OnInit {
  currentDate = new Date();

  contactInfo$: Observable<ContactInfo>;

  constructor(private contactInfoService: ContactInfoService) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.contactInfo$ = this.contactInfoService.getContactInformation();
    console.log(this.contactInfo$);
  }
}

Comment: I've updated the answer. Calling `callContactInfo()` from the constructor. See if this works.

Answer (score 0):

i got you problem...

**please check this code smoothly...**

**contact-info.service.ts :**

```
import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { Http} from '@angular/http';     //Updated...

  export class ContactInfoService {

  private apiUrl: string;
  public contactInfo = [];

  private endpoint = 'common/main-contact';

  constructor(private http: Http) {.        //Updated...
    this.apiUrl = environment.backendUrl;
  }

   //get request using operaters...

  getContactInformation() {
     return this.http.get('APIURL').pipe(map((response: any) =>response.json()));
   }

  getContactInformation(): Observable<ContactInfo> {
    return this.http.get<ContactInfo> (`${this.apiUrl}/${this.endpoint}`)
    .pipe(shareReplay(1));
  }

  setContactInfo(data) {
    this.contactInfo = data;
  }

  getContactInfo() {
    return this.contactInfo;
  }
}
```

**header.component.ts :**

```
 ngOnInit() {
     this.contactInfoService.getContactInformation().subscribe((res) => {
       this.contactInfoService.setContactInfo(res);
   }
 }
```

**footer.component.ts:**

```
ngOnInit() {
      let contactData = this.contactInfoService.getContactInfo()

      consolo.log(contactData)
   }
 }
```

Now you can use `this.contactInfoService.getContactInfo()` for contactInfo all over the project !

and **it will only one time send request to the server**

let me know if any help !

Comment: Thanks a lot, but with this  - GET request not working and received error: ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED

Comment: But it was working previously with the code in start of this conversation

Comment: is it Okay Now?

Comment: ERROR TypeError: response.json is not a function